# How to highlight a specific word in a String in JSP

Tags: java, html, css, string, jsp

I have a JSP where in a text area i am reading the String array of a whole sentence and printing it line by line. No i want to highlight some patter in the line in BOLD and red color font. e.g. if the line which is being read contains pattern "error" (it can be a single word or a part of a word like "initializationerror" or ""), i t will be highlighted in BOLD and red color. The rest of the line will be print as it is.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<table border="2">
<% 
    if(session.getAttribute("Result") != null)
    {
        String Result = (String) session.getAttribute("Result");
        if(Result.length() != 0)
        {
            String[] split_EOL = Result.split("\n");
%>
            <tr align="center"> 
                <td>
                    // Text area start here 
                    <textarea rows="50" cols="100" readonly="yes">   
<%
                        for(int i = 0; i < split_EOL.length; i++)
                        {
                            out.println(split_EOL[i]);
                            out.println(" ");
                        }
%>
                    </textarea>
                 </td>
             </tr>
<%
         }
    }
%>
</table>
```

Please help

I tried the following:

```
<textarea rows="50" cols="100" readonly="yes"> 
<% 
     for(int i=0;i<split_EOL.length ; i++){ 
     out.println(split_EOL[i].replaceAll("\\b\\w*"+Pattern+"\\w*\\b", "<b>$0</b>"));   
     out.println(" "); 

                                          }
%> 
</textarea>
```

here Pattern = ERROR..... but it displays like this

```
95323:[<b>ERROR</b>] Logger not set
```

even i trued to display some word in bold in out.println but it didnt render the bold tags:

```
 out.println("<b>"+Pattern+"</b>");%>
```

displays only

> ```
> <b>ERROR</b>
> ```

Comment: Have you written `Pattern = ERROR` or is it `Pattern = "ERROR"`?

Comment: I completely missed your `textarea`, sorry. This is a multi line text input entry, which doesn't allow text attributes. So my solution is only valid for text outside your textarea.

Comment: Look at this answer [How can I display bold text in a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9274621/1741542), maybe this is what you need.

Comment: So is there anyhting else i can use instead of textarea where i can display bold text.....My text area is read only so i dont need the user to edit...ther reason i used textarea was i have lots of lines to dislay so i can easily make it scrollabble

Comment: Hey @Olaf Dietsche    Thanks a lot for the help. I got a work around and used div tags instead of text area..all thanks to you make me realize in time that text area cant render html.    I have one more question regarding regex in the code.  How do you make it ignore case sensitivity?    Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the pattern `\b\w*error\w*\b` with a `<span class="error-string">$0</span>`

```
out.println(split_EOL[i].replaceAll("\\b\\w*error\\w*\\b", "<span class=\"error-string\">$0</span>"));
```

and define in CSS

```
error-string {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you need a case insensitive search, you can prefix your pattern with `(?i)`, see [Pattern - Special constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).

Comment: Bt how do i identify whether that pattern is present in the line....shall i brek the whole line ito tokens and match tokens with the word?  I am reading one full line from the array in every iteration.   And is there a way without css because i ahevnt use css in my jsp

Comment: @user2014600 You can use an inline style as Ali Bassam suggested, but I wouldn't recommend it. Using classes and CSS is cleaner than that.

Comment: I tried to use the following but its not rendering the html tags:    <textarea rows="50" cols="100" readonly="yes">
 <% 
 for(int i=0;i<split_EOL.length ; i++){
  //out.println(split_EOL[i]);
  out.println(split_EOL[i].replaceAll("\\b\\w*"+Pattern+"\\w*\\b", "<b>$0</b>"));
     out.println(" ");
 }%>
</textarea>                    here Pattern = ERROR..... but it displays like this               95323:[<b>ERROR</b>] Logger not set

Comment: View source display like this          &lt;b&gt;ERROR&lt;/b&gt;

Comment: @user2014600 Please add the updated code snippet to your question, it is easier to read there. If your replacement string is `<b>$0</b>` the output seems correct. What is your expected output?

Comment: Infact the truth is none of the html tags are getting rendered in the text area.......   I tried     <b><%=Pattern%></b>            but it  didnt worked

Comment: @user2014600 Please see my comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%if( //your condition )
  {
    out.println("<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:red; \"> Bla Bla Bla </span>");
  }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is:
string textString="this is my text i would like to highlight the word text";

string 
highlight= `"<mark>text</mark>";`
;

<%=textString.replaceAll("text",  highlight) %>