# How to bold selected text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text-editor

In a form's textarea, I'd like to allow users to select part of their text and by pressing a button, encompass the text with `<strong>` tags.

How to do this using jQuery?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: @Paul I tried to extract the relevant part from a lightweight text-editor but as I'm new to jQuery, it did not work at all. I also looked at several other SO questions but none addressed the `select text` part of my question.

Comment: You want to put the selected text between escaped `<strong>` tag like BBCode or make the text bold inside the textarea by using the tag `<strong>`?

Comment: @theFX I merely want to inject html tags so that it appear bold after being rendered (in Django template). I don't want to make a WYSIWYG behavior.

Comment: Have you taught of using http://ckeditor.com/ ?

Comment: @Vim I just hate all WYSIWYG editors, so using any of them is out of question :)

Comment: Here is another link which discuss the same topic... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274120/how-can-i-display-bold-text-in-a-textarea. The outcome is, there is no way to do it as of now.

Comment: can you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/XCb95/80/

Comment: @Sushil that's exactly what I need dude! go ahead post it and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: thanks @Randi. let me post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties to find the selected text. here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XCb95/80/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks!  I just needed to add `type="button"` into <button> tag, otherwise it caused unwanted submission of the form just on click.

Comment: you can create a normal input button then.