# Highlight (Select) text in textarea when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

```
var editor = document.getElementById ("editor-content");
var bold = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
bold.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, "**"+"boldtext"+"**");
editor.dispatchEvent(bold);
```

I am currently making a markdown editor with a textarea.

When a button is pressed, the above code will run.

It runs perfectly but I want the "boldtext"to be highlighted(selected) when it is inserted into the textarea.

How would I do this? Right now the cursor is put at the end of `**boldtext**`.

Like this.

`**boldtext|**`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display only one/few words in bold in a textarea unless you do something similar to what is mentioned: [How can I display bold text in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274120/how-can-i-display-bold-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. The textarea will show `**bold text**` by itself. What I want to do is when the button is pressed, the string 'bold text' will be selected.  `**bold text**` is what is getting inserted into the textarea.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085446/selecting-part-of-string-inside-an-input-box-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
editor.selectionStart -= 10;
editor.selectionEnd   -= 2;
```

This sets caret beginning to end relatively.

`**boldtext**`-10 to -2 is from after `t` to `b`